# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir" in deployed website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment

In my website I need to create a folder and save some file in it, my code works as long I'm running it in local, but once I've doplyed it on render I'm getting this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/opt/render/desktop/data/filename
[...]
Apr 24 07:37:41 PM    syscall: 'mkdir',
Apr 24 07:37:41 PM    code: 'ENOENT',
Apr 24 07:37:41 PM    path: '/opt/render/desktop/data/filename
```

This is the code I'm using to create the folder:

```
const fs = require("fs");

createFolder = (folderName) => {
  var dir = require("path").join(
    require("os").homedir(),
    `desktop/data/${filename}`
  );
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
};
```

I think the problem may be the path  `/opt/render/desktop/data/filename` .
How can I solve it?

Comment: You likely won’t be able to access the file system of the hosting machine in the exact same way you access your own local machine’s file system. Could be different folder structures, different permissions, different operating systems, etc.. You will most likely need (and probably should) look into uploading and hosting the files in cloud storage somewhere, assuming the generated file doesn’t contain secret keys and stuff. E.g. your app sends the file to an AWS bucket. Maybe you can still store files locally during local development.

Comment: Check that file path, it might be the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to create a full path, and not just a single level folder. Trying passing the `recursive parameter:` fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });`.

Also, I think you probably meant to specify `folderName` and not `filename` in the path?

One last thing: I recommend moving the `const path = require('path');` to the top of the file, rather than requiring it dynamically in the function. Same for `os`.